# Usb mic delay in win 10

Tags: usb, windows-10, microphone, delay

I have a usb microphone and if I enable "listen to this device" in Win 10, I have a delay of about half second.

I need to get rid of this delay. I have seen around the web that someone solved this using soundcard software, but I don't have any, just my drivers (the sound card works properly).

Any suggestions?

Comment: A USB mic has it's own sound card built into the device. Make sure your windows 10 is fully updated, and try checking to see if the usb mic has any drivers provided for it on it's support website. Also, try different USB ports. I had a very strange issue when using a USB2.0 audio device in a USB3.0 port. I could only fix it by using a USB2.0 port, which I had to source from an unpopulated motherboard USB header